# Can anyone explayme this formula to determine the coordinates where two circles intersect?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I want to find the coordinates of the points of intersection of two circles. I have the coordinates of the origin and end points and the radious of the circles.

[image]

Searching the internet I found this method.

http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/determine-where-two-circles-intersect-in-c/

I know and understand the Pythagorean theorem gives:

[image]

So:

[image]

Substituting [image] and multiplying this out gives:

[image]

And keep going until this:

[image]

But this last part I don´t know where come from... or what kind of formula is... or how we get that...

[image]

Can anyone explain me this formula please...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It is because we have a pair of similar triangles as shown in the figure.

Here we have

$$\frac{h}{d}=\frac{u}{x_0-x_1}=\frac{v}{y_0-y_1}$$

$$(x_3,y_3)=(x_2\mp v,y_2\pm u)=\left(x_2\pm\frac{h(y_1-y_0)}{d},y_2\mp\frac{h(x_1-x_0)}{d}\right)$$

Note:
The two triangles are similar:

[image]

$\alpha=180^\circ-90^\circ-\beta=90^\circ-\beta=\gamma=\delta$

$\varepsilon=180^\circ-90^\circ-\delta=180^\circ-90^\circ-\alpha=\beta$

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand... Can u explain me more in detail please.

Comment: The coordinates of $P_2$ are $(x_2,y_2)$. There are two possible positions of $P_3$. One is $v$ units to the left and $u$ units above $P_2$. Its coordinates are $(x_2-v,y_2+u)$. The other possible $P_3$ is at the position which is $v$ units to the right and $u$ units below $P_2$. Its coordinates are $(x_2+v,y_2-u)$. So we have to find $u$ and $v$. Can you see the pair of similar triangles?

Comment: Yes, I see the two triangles.. So, how to find to find "u" and "v"?

Comment: The corresponding sides are proportional. h and d are the hypotenuses. Their ratio is equal to the ratio of u to $x_0-x_1$ and the ratio of v to $y_0-y_1$, because of they are pairs of corresponding sides.

Comment: Oh I see. One more thing... What is the condition for these two triangles to be similar?

Comment: equiangular. Note that $P_0P_1\perp P_2P_3$

Comment: Can you explaime more about why triangle U,V,H is similar to D, Xo - X1, Y0 - Y1?

Comment: Thank you to take your time to answer all my questions! I appreciate it so much.